# Encoding problem when using htmlentities method

Tags: php, encoding

I've a problem of character encoding in php, so this's the php code:

```
n_event=$_GET['ndlann'];
$nom_complet=htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['nom']));
$email_comment=htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$titre_comment=htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['titre']));
$texte_comment=htmlentities(stripslashes(nl2br($_POST['commentaire'])));
$pays_comment=$_POST['pays'];
$date_ajout=date('Y/m/d');
```

Data will be added in a database table , you see that this data comes from a comments form,
so when the user enters some comments with orient languages carachters (arabic,hebrew...etc), the input data will change to something like :

> Ø´Ù�Ø±Ø§ Ø¹Ù�Ù� Ø§Ù�Ù�Ù�Ø¶Ù�Ø

I tried to delete the htmlentities method and that works fine , but does start another problem of comments form security (js scripts will be executed)

What can I do with this situation?

and thanks

Comment: Did you try to set charset in htmlentities to e.g. UTF-8?

Comment: how to do it? htmlentities($_POST['comment'],'charset=UTF-8') ??

Comment: @Simo TAQUI. Try this: htmlentities($_POST['comment'],ENT_COMPAT,'utf-8')

Comment: Okey, thank you ! +1, I'll try this, Just Taqi is without U :),

Comment: @Simo TAQI. Sorry for spelling mistake :-)

Comment: @Marcin , thank you that was useful , and now it's okey! :)

Comment: What is the type of `pays` field in the database?

Comment: the pays field is a varchar field in the database, it comes from a select element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Do not use htmlentities() ever.

This function has been obsoleted long time ago. 
Use `htmlspecialchars()` instead.

you have also bunch of nonsense in your code

- doing `htmlentities(nl2br(*))` has no sense.
- make stripslashes conditional, only if magic quotes are set on.
- there is a possible problem with `pays` field.
- I am also afraid that you're taking htmlentities as some sort of SQL escaing function. Am I right?

Comment: @Shrapnel , thank you for your answer friend, I will change my code.. but for the pays field , it comes from a select element and I think there's no problem with it :-) +1

Comment: @Simo you cannot be more wrong. That IS the problem. There is no matter what kind of field in terms of security.

Comment: @Shrapnet, I think u're right!, maybe someone can construct a new form but with a textarea with pays name.. and enter a javascript code. thank you for this note. +1

Comment: @Sharpnel, and for what purpose must make stripslashes conditional if only magic quotes are set on?? and thank you to clear the matters up. :)

Comment: @Simo because it's the only stripslashes purpose - to strip slashes added by magic quotes. Otherwise you may strip honest slash accidentally.

Comment: htmlentities(nl2br(*)) just try it and see if you get any desired result

Comment: for htmlentities , I've just noticed that the nl2br is used to respect returns to line, and htmlentities to ignore js scripts and html codes in the text, I don't see the matter!

Comment: Yeah, I used it in some website projects and it's okey (As I think)

Comment: but I often use it only with textarea fields, but I can't see the problem?

Comment: @Shrapnet, anyway thank you, I will consider to not use this htmlentities(nl2br(*)) in coming projects. (even if I don't know what's exactly the matter. :)

Comment: @Simo nl2br will add an HTML tag to your text (<br> one). BUT htmlentities WHLL MAKE ENTITIES OUT OF IT! So, it would be not a line break on the HTML page, but literal <br> as is! CAN'T YOU SEE THAT???

Comment: ah, thank you!? what a BAD PRACTICE! I didn't see that cause I used it only for comments, so I don't know if users've made a breakline or not

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, and according to [the PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlentities.php), the accepted answer is not correct. 
Nowhere it is written that this function has been deprecated.

If you set correctly the third argument of the function, called `$encoding`, it will solve your problem.

I hope this helps.